# Output 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column' (Python in Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

```py
def compute_statistics(age_and_salary_data):  
    histograms(age_and_salary_data)
    age = age_and_salary_data.column("Age")
    salary = age_and_salary_data.column("Salary")
    return make_array(np.mean(age), np.mean(salary))
    

full_stats = compute_statistics(full_data)
full_stats
```

This code is to:
Create a function called compute_statistics that takes a Table containing ages and salaries and:

Draws a histogram of ages
Draws a histogram of salaries
Return a two-element list containing the average age and average salary

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and do some research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you want to access a column, you can use brackets like age_and_salary_data["Age"] and age_and_salary_data["Salary"], this column function does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively to age_and_salary_data["Age"] you may use age_and_salary_data.Age